# Is it possible to get XML version of Standard Object

Tags: apex, integration, webservices

We have an Informatica job which runs every night that extracts Salesforce data and loads into MDM. We recently changed an Opportunity field name and my colleague need to synchronize the change with Informatica job. She is asking an XML version of our Opportunity object(metadata) which I am not sure if it's possible to get it. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is she looking for an XML version of the *data* (as in one specific record)? Or is she looking for an XML version of the *metadata* (as in the object configuration)?

Comment: Metadata. As she is not able to edit her schema, she want to synchronise using an XML version of the sObject.

Comment: When you extract the metadata information for any object, it is represented in XML. You can do so using any IDE or Force.com migration tool.

Comment: @JayantDas -  I tried using Force.com IDE and we are able to get it for Custom object, but standard objects are not available under Objects list though I selected Standard Objects from metadata components list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you need the correct package.xml. The tool of choice doesn't matter, so long as you have the right file. Sometimes the Force.com IDE can get this file wrong, so make sure the src/package.xml file looks exactly like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>Opportunity</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
  </types>
</Package>
```

Then, try retrieving the object again (Right-click > Force.com > Retrieve From Server).

Alternatively, you can use the same package.xml in VS Code with the DX extension, using Salesforce DX directly from the command-line, using the [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/), [aside.io](https://aside.io/), or any of a number of free or paid tools out there.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to see Opportunity object definition now. But my colleague is not happy with this format. So is there a way to get Standard Object record in XML format without programming?

Comment: @Amulya I don't think your colleague knows what they're asking for, then. XML is a generic markup language, related to SGML, HTML, XHTML, and so on. It only defines how tags and attributes work plus a few special features like entity encoding, CDATA, etc. The file you got, however you got it, is the standard metadata XML format for Salesforce. If they want something else, they're going to need to be more specific.

Comment: Right she wasn't clear. Now I got the XML of Opportunity record and she is fine with it. Thank you very much.!!